# Free Software for removing watermark from PDF

Tags: linux, open-source, pdf, digital-watermarking

I use [Trisquel GNU/Linux](https://trisquel.info) 7.0 (based on Ubuntu 14.04).

I am looking for [Free](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html) [Software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) for removing watermark from PDF. We know that PDF may contain image or text as watermark, I'm more concerned about the image as watermark.

You can suggest CLI as well as GUI tools/utility for removing watermark from PDF file.

Comment: Have a look at this thread [remove watermark from pdf](http://superuser.com/questions/448519/how-to-remove-watermark-from-pdf-using-pdftk).

Comment: @Vembu That I've already tried. BUT it is only for removing simple text-watermark whereas I am talking about image as well as text as water mark (mentioned in question).

Comment: From the point of view of a machine the text/images that human beings perceive as being a watermark are just ordinary content. How would a machine know what content to remove? You are asking something that is impossible except if the watermark is marked as a watermark (but that's hardly ever the case).

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?